# Parsing XML from app bundle instead of an URL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

I'm building an application that parses XML from an online server. I want to cache the XML file locally for 24 hours. How can I change the following code to read from a file in my resource directory?

```
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the path for your xml file like the following:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourxml" ofType:@"xml"];
```

and then obtain a NSData instance like the following:

```
NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

and finally call

`initWithData` method of `NSXMLParser`.

**But** you cannot modify the content of your application bundle. Files in the bundle (the resources directory you asked for) cannot be modified.

There are different way to do it:

- grab the file from the web and save it in a property-list file
- use `NSFileManager` class to save and read your xml file

An example with `NSFileManager`:

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourxml.xml"];
```

The snippet grab the xml file path contained in your Documents directory. It means that there is already a file there. For further info see [NSFileManager class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager)

Hope it helps.